# Numeric string sorting with letters and numbers in Groovy

Tags: string, sorting, groovy, numeric

simple question, don't know if it gets a simple answer.
Is there a way to sort a list of string wich contains letters and numbers, but considering the numbers as well?

For example, my list contains:

```
(1) ["Group 1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group10", "Group20", "Group30"]
```

(The strings doesn't have the word "group" necessarily, it could have others words)

if I sort it, it shows:

```
(2)
Group 1
Group 10
Group 2
Group 20
Group 3
Group 30
```

Is there a way to sort it like (1) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
def test=["Group 1", "Group2", "Group3", "2", "Group20", "Group30", "1", "Grape 1", "Grape 12", "Grape 2", "Grape 22"]

test.sort{ a,b ->
    def n1 = (a =~ /\d+/)[-1] as Integer
    def n2 = (b =~ /\d+/)[-1] as Integer

    def s1 = a.replaceAll(/\d+$/, '').trim()
    def s2 = b.replaceAll(/\d+$/, '').trim()

    if (s1 == s2){
        return n1 <=> n2
    }
    else{
        return s1 <=> s2
    }
}

println test
```

If you want to compare first the number you have to change the internal *if* with:

```
if (n1 == n2){
    return s1 <=> s2
}
else{
    return n1 <=> n2
}
```

This take te last number it found in the string, so you can write what do you want, but the 'index' should be the last number

Comment: Very nice try bro, but test with this: `def test= ["Group 1", "Group2", "Group3", "2", "Group20", "Group30", "1", "Grape 1", "Grape 12", "Grape 2", "Grape 22"]`

Comment: What should be the results? It should check first the number than the string? or first the string than the number?

Comment: Showing println from test `[Group 1, 1, Grape 1, Group2, 2, Grape 2, Group3, Grape 12, Group20, Grape 22, Group30]` What order do you see here?

Comment: Really cool man! +10. You could be more succinct with `s1 <=> s2 : n1 <=> n2`

Comment: I don't like too much that kind of sintax :P

Comment: Yes. Sorry, typo. Should be `s1 <=> s2 ?: n1 <=> n2` instead of `s1 <=> s2 : n1 <=> n2`. It works.

Comment: But it doesn' work...I had this error Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'java.lang.Number'
 at order.run(order.groovy:3)

Comment: And maybe an `if` to check that `integer` exists. But that is too much. Great answer bro.

Comment: This is really great, thank you very much.
I had come with an 'ugly' workaround, but it only sorted by numbers.
This is it if anyone cares:  <br/>

`def grupos = ["Group 1", "Group2", "Group3", "2", "Group20", "Group30", "1", "Grape 1", "Grape 12", "Grape 2", "Grape 22"]`  

`println grupos.sort{it.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "")!= ""? it.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "").toLong() : it};`

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string in two sub-strings and then sort them separately.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
def myList= ["Group 1", "Group2", "Group3", "2", "Group20", "Group30", "1", "Grape 1"]
print (myList.sort { a, b -> a.compareToIgnoreCase b })
```